# How to filter an table by a value in row Angular JS button click

Tags: angularjs

I have a button in my view. When I press my button I want to filter my table. My table have element called market it can be "ios" or "android". When I press "ios" button I want to show only data which have "ios" as market. In default table view all data (both ios and android).

button

```
<button ng-click="applyiosfilter()">Search</search>
```

table

```
<tr dir-paginate="datad in downloadsdata|filter:downloadfilter"> ...
</tr>
```

arrays for sore data

```
$scope.downloadsdata = [];
$scope.downloadfilter = [];
```

add data in to scope

```
$scope.applyiosfilter = function() {
    angular.forEach($scope.downloadsdata, function(value, key) {
        if(value.market==='ios') {
            $scope.downloadfilter[key] = $scope.downloadsdata[key];
        }
    });
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try filter function as:

```
<button ng-click="applyiosfilter()">Search</search>
<tr dir-paginate="datad in downloadsdata|filter:applyfilter"> ...</tr>

$scope.applyiosfilter = function() {
    $scope.applyfilter = function(datad) { 
        return datad.Market.toLowerCase().indexOf('ios') != -1    
   };
};
```

EDIT: This will be fired only when the button is clicked.

Comment: this is not return correct value.how datad get data? data is in "value" variable in forEach loop

Comment: what is the meaning of != -1 here?

Comment: if the string does not match your query('ios'), it would `return -1`, the whole expression evaluates to `false` and that item is not part of the filtered array.